# Updating plugin/module config via template/controller

Tags: plugin-development, config

I have a plugin/module that synchronises local records with a Google Sheet managed by the client.
The URL for this doc is stored in a module config.

I want the client to be able to update this via the control panel so have created a template for editing and a controller to update the config. This is all fine locally but in the client environment where `allowAdminChanges` is set to false this won't save and I get the following error:

```
 Changes to the project config are not possible while in read-only mode.
```

I have tried both `Craft::$app->projectConfig->set('my-module', $settings);` and `Craft::$app->getSystemSettings()->saveSettings('mud-module', $settings)` with same ersponse.

Is there a way to update config when `allowAdminChanges` is set to 0/false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no. If this is config or data which are environment specific, they are as likely not good candidates for project config. Perhaps consider moving them to a table and access them through a Record/Model?